# ViewPager setCurrentItem() doesn't call the onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 18 pages in my MainAcitivity, and after clicking a button in one page, it jumped to another acitivity called NewActiviy. When I click back button in NewActivity, I want to return to the last page of MainActivity.The Fragment of last page is called FinishFragment. So I add  setCurrentItem() in onResumed() function of MainAcitity. But I found that the OnCreateView() of FinishFragment is not called when setCurrentItem() is called. So the view in FinishFragment is not initialized. But I use the view in setUserVisibleHint()function and view is null, so some errors occurred. Could anyone help explain why onCreateView()is not called and how should I solve this problem.

Comment: What happens if you try onViewStateRestored instead? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: What do you mean by `the last page of MainActivity`? Page 18 or the page that was last visited?

Comment: Btw depending on the adapter you use, only a few fragments is loaded. So if you init the ViewPager and then scroll to the end, it will take a small amount of time before the fragment is available

Comment: @cYrixmorten you mean use onViewStateRestored to replace the setUserVisibleHint()? The reason why I use setUserVisibleHint() is a little complex. I try to explain. I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter , so on default, three pages will be stored in memory and when the 17th page is loaded, the 18th page is already created. In the 18th page, I will use some datas which may be moidified by the 17th page to update the some TextView. So I have to do these updates when the 18th is visible, otherwise, These TextViews were not updated correctly.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Yes I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. So three fragments are loaded. But is it related to the setCurrentItem()? In onCreate() function of MainActivity,  I have add the adapter to viewpager. I don't understand what will happen after setCurrentItem()

Comment: @iRuth It's the Page 18. so I just call setCurrentItem(17) in onResume

Comment: What about the other pages of the `ViewPager`? Are there buttons that do stuff there as well?

Comment: @iRuth I have tried the other pages. And it works well. The other pages didn't has the button do that .The problem is that I used the view in setUserVisibleHint(). But the onCreateView is not called(I found that by debug), so the view is null.

Comment: Can you check if the view is still null when `onResume` is called in the fragment?